# Preg_Match a string in the form of a URL

Tags: php, regex, string

I have a URL as a string. How do I match the numbers after the VideoID. Also VideoID may occur at different points in the URL. But I will worry about that afterwards, as I can't even do this.

```
$string = 'http://example.com/index.php?action=vids.individual&VideoID=60085484';

preg_match('/(?<VideoID>)=/', $string, $matches);

print_r($matches);
```

...Spare some change for a noob. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use the built-in [`parse_url`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php)/[`parse_str`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php)

```
$string = 'http://example.com/index.php?action=vids.individual&VideoID=60085484';
$URL = parse_url($string);
parse_str($URL['query'],$Q);
print_r($Q);
```

returns

> ```
> Array (  
>     [action] => vids.individual  
>     [VideoID] => 60085484
> )
> ```

Answer (score 1):

```
/(?:\?|&)VideoID=([0-9]+)/   # get just the ID, stored in \\1
/(?:\?|&)(VideoID=[0-9]+)/   # get VideoId=ID, stored in \\1
```

Under the assumption that your URL is properly formed, it will always be preceded by either `?` or `&`, and with your example the URL is strictly numerical, so it will match a valid ID up to the next segment of the URL.

Comment: (?:\?|&) can also be expressed as [?&]

Answer (score 0):

```
$string = 'http://example.com/index.php?action=vids.individual&VideoID=60085484&somethingelse';
$s = explode("VideoID=",$string);
print preg_replace("/[^0-9].*/","",$s[1]);
```

Comment: Will fail if VideoID is not at the end of the URL